# Http error code status changes from 405 to 401 (spring boot 2 and jetty)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jetty

thanks for taking your time to look into this issue. I have been working on a spring boot 2 application and i have added a custom filter (DisabledHttpMethodFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter implements Ordered) for not to allow TRACE and OPTIONS method calls. I am throwing error (SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = 405). the filter seems to be working and does not allow TRACE and OPTIONS calls but there is some issue and http status code is changing from 405 to 401. I have debugged the issue multiple times and could not find root cause behind it.
I am attaching the screen shot from my debug. the error code changes in handlers and dispatcher method stack.

in the below screen its is visible that from filter class status code 405 is getting thrown.
[image]

No middle filter/handler causes any harm and things goes smooth till HttpChannel class.
[image]

From this class codes to ErrorHandler ( i am skipping a lot of classes and their screen shots. just trying to show the intermediate stage. Still 405 code )
[image]

and then in one of handle/dispatch method it changes from 405 to 401.
[image]

Please let me know what could be the wrong there. I have a parallel application in which same filter works fine. I have debugged both the application in parallel but i am getting lost in method stack. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reach the `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler` then it is important to know that your *response has been reset* before reaching that code.

This behavior is per the Servlet spec.

It means that all response headers, buffers, and values are reset to default (with the one notable exception being `java.servlet.http.Cookie` objects being tracked in the response).

General Servlet and/or Jetty advice.

First, `TRACE` is disabled by default on all WebApps, but this being Spring, all bets are off (as it thinks it knows better than the container).

Next, disabling HTTP methods is done in the Servlet spec via Constraints, not Filters. (just like the disabled TRACE method)

```xml
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Enable everything but TRACE</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <http-method-omission>TRACE</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
```

Advice for your `DisabledHttpMethodFilter`.

Your `DisabledHttpMethodFilter` should avoid using `OncePerRequestFilter`, it's inappropriate for terminal behaviors (where you don't want to process more things in Spring).  The filter stack in Spring will essentially undo your efforts as a result of using the spring filters as your base.

The `Ordered` behaviors are fine to make sure your `Filter` is in the correct place, but even that is ultimately not needed for success.

If your `DisabledHttpMethodFilter` uses `HttpServletResponse.sendError()` then you should make sure you have a custom Error handling for response code 405 in your spring application that essentially does nothing. (to prevent spring and jetty from undoing your efforts)

If your `DisabledHttpMethodFilter` uses `HttpServletResponse.setStatus()` and returning without calling the filter chain, then you have nothing else to do (but it would be trivially easy to wind up with extra response headers that can conflict with your intentions.  Like having cache headers on the response for status codes where they are inappropriate)

A better approach for `DisabledHttpMethodFilter` would be for it to throw a custom exception, say `MethodDisabledException` and a custom error handling registered with spring and/or Jetty for that exception that simply sets the status code to 405.  This allows the response reset to happen (a good thing!), and it minimizes other Spring dispatch behaviors from executing and changing your intent.